# Preventing connecting some nodes in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am constructing an undirected graph G by connecting nodes using an precalculated adjacency matrix. Based on this graph, connected components will be analyzed. I use MATLAB's builtin graph() function for this. However, I have a constraint: some nodes (known) cannot appear in the same connected component. Of course, I zero out the indices of adjacency matrix associated with these nodes, but connections via other nodes are still possible. I am looking for an algorithm (or a trick) to prevent these unwanted connections.

Comment: Could you specify? I will edit the question respectively.

Comment: If you ONLY have this one constraint, then it is trivial to come with any number of simple algorithms to produce  graphs that satisfy.  Most of them unlikely to be interesting or useful for what you want to do.

Comment: So your real question is something like this:  find the minimum number of links that have to be removed from a graph so that the specified nodes will not be reachable from each other.

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: So edit your question.  Tag it with matlab.  Give an example where your algorithm does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET D to nodes that must not be connected
LOOP P over every node pair in D
    LOOP
        Find path between P ( Dijkstra )
        IF path exists
            remove link from middle of path
        ELSE
            BREAK
```